# Store values in an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to store values in an array of pointers. I have done the below so far but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
#include <fstream>          //for file IO (ifstream)
#include <iostream>         //for cin >> and cout <<

using namespace std;

#define MAX_N 1000

int *ptr[MAX_N]; //It declares ptr as an array of MAX integer pointers

int myptr = 0;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        myptr++;
    }
    
    ptr[0] = &myptr; // assign the address of integer
    cout << *ptr[0] << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        myptr++;
    }
    
    ptr[1] = &myptr; // assign the address of integer
    cout << *ptr[1] << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) { 
        cout << "Value of element " << i << ": " << *ptr[i] << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I want the the last loop outputs:

```
Value of element 0: 3

Value of element 1: 5
```

But it gives me:

```
Value of element 0: 5

Value of element 1: 5
```

Apparently, I am missing something. Both elements point to the same address which I cannot understand because the variable `myptr` changes its values.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting the address of myptr (`&myptr`) to change?

Comment: yes, this is what I want but I cannot make it. I want that the array ptr holds different addresses. And these addresses should correspond the values of &myptr.

Comment: Actually, this result is expected result.
You are assigning address of myPtr variables to ptr[0] and value is 3 and after that you are assigning address of myPtr again to ptr[1] and value is 5 now. As a result, ptr[0] and ptr[1] has the address of myPtr and value is 5.I think if you want to assign address of myPtr, you cannot take different value because they have same address.

Comment: calling an integer `myptr` is an interesting creative choice

Comment: When both pointers point to the same object, they will both show the same value when dereferenced. You are the same person whether you're refereed to by your name or the number on an ID card.

Comment: That is to say, the right hand side of this assignment `ptr[0] = &myptr;`  and this assignment `ptr[1] = &myptr;` do not only read the same in code but they also evaluate to the same thing, because they both reference the same place in program memory, the place created when you did `int myptr = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

You just make both pointers point to the same memory address. You never allocate additional memory for more `int`s which is why you always read the value currently stored in `myptr`. To allocate additional memory use `new` and don't forget to free all the newly allocated memory at the end:

```
#define MAX_N 1000

// make sure the pointers are initialized as null pointers
int* ptr[MAX_N] { nullptr }; //It declares ptr as an array of MAX integer pointers

int myptr = 0;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        myptr++;
    }

    ptr[0] = new int(myptr); // dynamically create an int with the value currently stored in myptr
    cout << *ptr[0] << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        myptr++;
    }

    ptr[1] = new int(myptr); // allocate another int
    cout << *ptr[1] << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        cout << "Value of element " << i << ": " << *ptr[i] << endl;
    }

    // free all the allocated ints (delete null doesn't hurt)
    for (int* p : ptr)
    {
        delete p;
    }

    return 0;
}
```